# Gson: JsonParser.parse() cannot recognize invalid JSON format

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I want to validate a JSON string by using `com.google.gson.JsonParser`. By this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791878/reliable-json-string-validator-in-java), I know that `JsonParser.parse()` is lenient enough to treat invalid **abc** as valid **"abc"**. That is to say, `JsonParser.parse()` will not throw a `JsonSyntaxException` or `JsonParseException` for the string below:

```
abc
```

By adding the logic of **jsonElement.isJsonObject()**, the following code can recognize invalid JSON string of **abc**.

```
boolean isJSON(String jsonString) {

  try {
    JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);

    if (!jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
      return false;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

However, it still cannot recognize invalid JSON format from the following strings.

```
{"name": mike}
```

or

```
{name: mike}
```

How to recognize invalid JSON for these cases?

Comment: I'm not going to modify 3rd party code, neither am I able to change the input string. I just want to make a strong JSON validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `JsonParser` for a couple of reasons:

- It uses lenient `JsonReader` under the hood.
- It creates a JSON document view in memory (`JsonElement`) that is definitely not a way to go for not small documents.

You can use `JsonReader` safely:

```java
private static boolean isJsonValid(final String json)
        throws IOException {
    return isJsonValid(new StringReader(json));
}

private static boolean isJsonValid(final Reader reader)
        throws IOException {
    return isJsonValid(new JsonReader(reader));
}

private static boolean isJsonValid(final JsonReader jsonReader)
        throws IOException {
    try {
        JsonToken token;
        while ( (token = jsonReader.peek()) != END_DOCUMENT && token != null ) {
            skipToken(jsonReader);
        }
        return true;
    } catch ( final MalformedJsonException ignored ) {
        return false;
    }
}

// Maybe skipToken will be a part of Gson someday: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1054
private static void skipToken(final JsonReader reader)
        throws IOException {
    final JsonToken token = reader.peek();
    switch ( token ) {
    case BEGIN_ARRAY:
        reader.beginArray();
        break;
    case END_ARRAY:
        reader.endArray();
        break;
    case BEGIN_OBJECT:
        reader.beginObject();
        break;
    case END_OBJECT:
        reader.endObject();
        break;
    case NAME:
        reader.nextName();
        break;
    case STRING:
    case NUMBER:
    case BOOLEAN:
    case NULL:
        reader.skipValue();
        break;
    case END_DOCUMENT:
    default:
        throw new AssertionError(token);
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    System.out.println(isJsonValid("\"abc\""));
    System.out.println(isJsonValid("{\"name\": \"mike\"}"));
    System.out.println(isJsonValid("abc"));
    System.out.println(isJsonValid("{\"name\": mike}"));
    System.out.println(isJsonValid("{name: mike}"));
    System.out.println(isJsonValid("{name: \"mike\"}"));
}
```

The test above produces:

> true
>   true
>   false
>   false
>   false
>   false

Comment: @yasi Hm, I'm not at the desktop at the moment, but the code line you mentioned should print `true` according to the JSON spec, and the test prints the same. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I was typing too long. :)

Comment: Yes, the code should print true for "abc", my mistake. However, by reading http://www.json.org/ (the legend on right side of it), I think "abc" is invalid JSON format string since any JSON "object" begins with "{" and ends with "}". However, online JSON validator, http://jsonlint.com/ , validates it's valid JSON string. Please help me out for the confusion.

Comment: @yasi Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json - it's confusing me though.